# Unicode characters emoticons in MySQL with 4 bytes

Tags: mysql, unicode, emoticons

I have to insert in Mysql Strings that may contain characters like '' . I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
MODIFY `colname` VARCHAR(200)
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

and when I insert '';

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col_name`) VALUES ('');
```

I get the following

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`;
```

> ????

How can I do to get the correct value in the select statements?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you set the connection encoding? Does your MySQL client use a font that supports such character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to set the *connection encoding* to `utf8mb4` as well. It depends on how you connect to MySQL how  to do this. `SET NAMES utf8mb4` is the API-independent SQL query to do so.

What MySQL calls `utf8` is a dumbed down subset of actual UTF-8, covering only the BMP (characters `0000` through `FFFF`). `utf8mb4` is *actual* UTF-8 which can encode all Unicode code points. If your connection encoding is `utf8`, then all data is squeezed though this subset of UTF-8 and you cannot send or receive characters above the BMP to or from MySQL.